# drupal----recommend modules to learn

Tags: php, drupal, module

i want to write modules by myself very much. but for drupal and php, i am not good at them, only on the learning way of them.but i like them very much. so i am sincerely expect some seasoned drupalers or gurus can recommend some simple modules for me to research and learn.i know  CCK and views are very popular,but they are too big. it's hard to learn from it for a newbie. any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything you come across in a module is some form of callback (`hook` in Drupal-speak), so I don't think you'll be able to learn much just by looking into the code of them. Rather it should be one part of a strategy that will involve lots of trips to http://api.drupal.org

The best candidates for study are the core modules as you're likely to be familiar with what they do already and, well, more eyeballs equals better code generally. `Path` might be a good one to start with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of example modules at http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/example.module where you can learn how to implement certain hooks and get a taste of module development in general. You can download them all from http://drupal.org/project/examples.